# How to add Paypal IPN into my website for getting subscription status after few days

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am creating recurring payment using paypal and want the status of the payment after few days.I mean i want to check user is still subscribe us or cancel the subscription. if he/she cancel the subscription or i want to update his status into my website.

Can you anyone help me out please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Standard subscriptions or NVP/SOAP recurring payments APIs when you will get an IPN when the profile is canceled, so you can automate the processing of that.  In the case of recurring payments APIs you could also use [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) any time you want to check the status.

If you are using REST API billing agreements / billing plans then you can use Webhooks, which are similar to IPN.  You could also use [GET to pull plan details](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans).

Comment: Okey Can you check my code i am using this code form getting Status.